# IllegalStateException “The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification”

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I am having `ListView` with `SimpleCursorAdapter`

**Error I am getting**:-

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131361944, class
>   android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class
>   com.pocketpharmacist.adapter.DrugClassesListAdapter)]

**When:-**

In my `Fragment` I have enabled the filtering with the adapter, and to filter the List I got one `EditText`.

Now,
1) when I start entering the text for filter **Virtual Keyboard comes alive**, and It starts filtering with the **list**

2)but, the real filtering comes alive when i hides the Keybord. and If i **click on listItem** with the **keybord alive** it gives me the above error, which is obvious because data is not reflected to UI

After going in to deep I got to know that **for example** I want to **search ABCDE** in a list I have entered ABC in Edittext now when i add D it shows me the filter for ABC and now again if I add **E** it **shows** me the filter for **ABCD**, **Buuut** Data is originally changed in the background. which is the cause of error.

But I am not able to figure out how to solve this

notifyDataSetChangedhas no effects, please Help me with this, any hint or idea can work

Hear is my code

Method from `TextWatcher`

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    searchAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
    searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    drugListView.requestLayout();       
}
```

Logcat is as below

```
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131361944, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.pocketpharmacist.adapter.DrugClassesListAdapter)]
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1555)
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922):     at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForTap.run(AbsListView.java:2840)
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
06-30 18:14:54.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6922):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have changed the method for filtration instead of writing

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    searchAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
    searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    drugListView.requestLayout();       
}
```

I have changed it and start using [FilterListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#filter%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.Filter.FilterListener%29) 
and called `notifyDataSetChanged` in that method and now everything works like charm

Answer (score 0):

Adapter is a part of UI, so you need to ensure this that it is not requested from a background thread, than it requires to request it from UI thread. Please go to [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) and search for Adapter. this site tutorial will guide you properly.